# Why no type mismatch in call to CoCreateInstance function in the Windows API?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I'm trying to translate [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--receiving-event-notifications-through-wmi-) example of calling the WMI/COM using winapi from C++ to Rust, but there's something I don't understand in the original code. Here's a function call in the C++ code:

```
hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,             
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);
```

What puzzles me is the *type* of the first and fourth arguments. Take the fourth argument, for example. If we look at [the definition of CoCreateInstance](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/um/combaseapi.h), the fourth argument is of type `REFIID` which in turn [is defined as a](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/bbde795f-5398-42d8-9f59-3613da03c318) `*IID` where an `IID` [is defined as a](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/94ea3f27-ba29-45f3-a821-323f0a0c6d60) `GUID`. So the fourth argument should be a pointer to a `GUID` object.

But if you look at [what I think is the definition](https://github.com/Aekras1a/Labs/blob/master/Labs/WinDDK/3790.1830/src/general/wmicli/gui/wmicli.h) of `IID_IWbemLocator`, it's defined as a `GUID` (using the `DEFINE_GUID` macro). So it looks like we're passing a `GUID` as an argument when really we should be passing a pointer to a `GUID`. *Why does this code compile?*

By comparison, in Rust I have to pass a reference to `IID_IWbemLocator`.

Apologies if the answer is really simple, I'm pretty unfamiliar with both C++ and the Winapi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the third argument is of type REFIID which in turn is defined as a *IID where an IID is defined as a GUID. So the third argument should be a pointer to a GUID object.

The documentation you linked is incorrect. I suspect it was written for C.

In C++, REFIID and REFCLSID are defined as IID references in Windows headers, like so:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define REFIID const IID &
#else
#define REFIID const IID * __MIDL_CONST
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
#define REFCLSID const IID &
#else
#define REFCLSID const IID * __MIDL_CONST
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you! Googling the code you provided, I found [this](https://books.google.se/books?id=kfRWvKSePmAC&pg=PA374&lpg=PA374&dq=%23define+REFIID+const+IID+%26&source=bl&ots=o9hWf79Lgu&sig=ACfU3U2mn4C2CApv6Fh332nLHS1XPQaBaA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%23define%20REFIID%20const%20IID%20%26&f=false) which confirms that it's a C vs. C++ issue.